# Issue with Indexing new Branches and Tags in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Our environment uses Jenkins for CICD hooked into Stash for version control.

I have a general question about the indexing of new branches and tags from Stash into Jenkins on a multibranch pipeline to run jobs. It seems the indexing processes takes a long time (like 30min-1hour), even when the config on the Jenkins job is set to scan the multibranch pipeline every minute, there is still a large delay before the branch/tag actually appears in Jenkins and runs.

I am new to the internals of Jenkins and am not quite sure exactly where to start with this problem. There definitely appears to be capacity on the worker nodes, so perhaps it's a contention issue on the controller? I don't actually manage the Jenkins environment myself, I just use it to run my own jobs, and want to suggest a few options we can look into to fix it.

Also worth mentioning that commits to branches already indexed to Jenkins run immediately, it is only new branches that incur this delay.

Any and all advice on where to start would be great.

This plugin is enabled on the system https://wiki.jenkins.io/JENKINS/Priority-Sorter-Plugin.html. After adding my own jobs to it, previously indexed branches run immediately (though they did not before). It didn't have any affect on newly created branches or tags.